# Error calling AssociateAddress- AWS Transfer family

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-transfer-family

I have tried to create AWS Transfer family in VPC public subnet from console. It failed with below error
"Error calling AssociateAddress: You are not authorized to perform this operation". Decoded the message to find that missing it missing permission for ec2:AssociateAddress

Added below policy to the role. Still the error persist while creating server. Can you please help

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ec2:AssociateAddress",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:111111:elastic-ip/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AssociateAddress` does not only apply to `elastic-ip`. You should try with:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ec2:AssociateAddress",
            "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:111111:elastic-ip/*",
               "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:111111:instance/*",
               "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:111111:network-interface/*",
             ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It did not help. do we need to tweak something in Trust Relationship ?

Comment: @sam I don't  know. Your question does not provide any information about Trust Relationship.